# boto3 codecommit create_commit issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, aws-codecommit

When trying to create a commit using boto3's codecommit client, somehow I got `AttributeError` on `create_commit`, but other commands works as expected.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
client = boto3.client(
            'codecommit',
            aws_access_key_id=access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
        )

resp = client.create_commit(
            repositoryName='my_repo',
            branchName='master',
            authorName='My Name',
            email='my_email@gmail.com',
            putFiles=[
                {
                    'filePath': '1.json',
                    'fileMode': 'NORMAL',
                    'fileContent': '%s' % (content, ),
                }
            ]
        )
```

Repository is an empty so `parentCommitId` is not required.

And it says:

```
AttributeError: 'CodeCommit' object has no attribute 'create_commit'
```

Does anyone face this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I asked my same issue to AWS Support, and I got an answer.

This issues happens because current AWS Lambda runtime (Python 3.7) is using Boto3 library of v1.9.42. and this version of the library does not contains contains `create_commit` API.

Recommended Workaround is uploading a deployment package containing the latest Boto3 python package (v.1.9.202) and Lambda python code.

Check this out: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Answer (score 0):

Check for boto3 version installed in your system using

```
pip show boto3
```

---

If the system version is 1.9 kindly upgrade it to v1.16 since v1.9 does not have the ***create_commit*** API.

---

If there are dependencies on v1.9 then create a virtual environment

> In Mac / Ubuntu

```
python3 -m venv env
```

> In Windows

```
py -m venv env
```

Reference links to Boto3 versions -

- [Boto3 Version 1.9](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.46/reference/services/codecommit.html)
- [Boto3 Version 1.16](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html)